# When I add a LEFT OUTER JOIN, the query returns only a few rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

The original query returns 160k rows. When I add the LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_Z Z WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id = Z.Id
```

the query returns only 150 rows. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

All I need to do is add a column to the query, which will bring back a code from a different table. The code could be a number or a NULL. I still have to display NULL, hence the reason for the LEFT join. They should join on the "id" columns.

```
SELECT <lots of stuff> + the new column that I need (called "code").
FROM 
    dbo.Table_A A WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Table_B B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.version = B.version

--this is where I added the LEFT OUTER JOIN. with it, the query returns 150 rows, without it, 160k rows.    
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table_Z Z WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Id = Z.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table_E E WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.agent = E.agent
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table_D D WITH (NOLOCK) ON E.location = D.location
                            AND E.type = 'Organization'
                            AND D.af_type = 'agent_location'
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT X , MAX(Version) AS MaxVersion 
     FROM LocalTable WITH (NOLOCK) 
     GROUP BY agemt) P ON E.agent = P.location AND E.Version = P.MaxVersion
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue?

Comment: We are going to need some schema.

Comment: A left outer join should not reduce the number of rows.  Are you sure you didn't change any other joins (such as the first inner join) or other conditions?

Comment: is there a `WHERE` clause?  Alot of times these issue arise when people reference something from a LEFT joined table in the where clause

Comment: found out the issue. the issue was actually in the SELECT statement. The column I added needed to be put in a ISNULL() clause. the query is now returning the correct number of rows. thanks for help guys.

Comment: How the inclusion or not of a function in the `SELECT` list can possibly change the number of rows returned? I wonder...

Comment: There is something you are not telling us I'm afraid. Is there any user defined function in the query? Any more `WHERE` clause you omitted?

Comment: Is that `AND E.type = 'Organization'` in the right place (or typo'd for the table alias)?  While completely valid, that type of relationship isn't usually what people want.  Also, what is the relationship between `E` and `D`?  If rows in `D` always exist for rows in `E`, I'd probably do a nested `INNER JOIN`, which would probably be clearer.

Comment: there is a massive where clause. i think the issue is there. it isn't taking into account this new column i added and nulls. the where clause is too big for me to put here plus, i have to change the names of everything due to private info or whatnot.

Comment: If the `WHERE` clause uses any of the `Z` columns, that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between tables `A` and `E`, you are maintaining your original set of data from `A`.  That is to say, there is no data, or lack of data, in table `E` that can reduce the number of rows in your query.

However, when you then perform an INNER JOIN between `E` and `P` at the bottom, you are indeed opening yourself up to the possibility of reducing the number of rows returned.  This will treat your subsequent `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s like `INNER JOIN`s.

Now, without your exact schema and a set of data to test against, this may or may not be the exact issue you are experiencing.  Still, as a general rule, always put your `INNER JOIN`s before your `OUTER JOIN`s.  It can make writing queries like this much, much easier.  Your most restrictive joins come first, and then you won't have to worry about breaking any of your outer joins later on.

As a quick fix, try changing your last join to `P` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, just to see if the `Z` join works.

Comment: "This will treat your subsequent LEFT OUTER JOINs like INNER JOINs." --- this is not true. `LEFT JOIN` is always a `left join`. Generally the order of joins doesn't matter - when DBMS creates an execution plan and executes it - the joins are performed in an order DBMS wants, not in the original one.

Comment: @zerkms Poorly worded, I suppose.  What I meant to say was that any rows in E that were not excluded by the outer join would be excluded by the following inner join to P.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful once you start with LEFT JOINs. 
Let's suppose this model: You have tables **Products**, **Orders** and **Customers**. Not all products necessarily have been ordered, but every order must have customer entered.

**Task:** Show all products, and if the product was ordered, list the ordering customers; i.e., product without orders will be shown as one row, product with 10 orders will have 10 rows in the resultset. This calls for a query designed around `FROM Products LEFT JOIN Orders`.

Now someone could think "OK, Customer is always entered into orders, so I can make `inner join from orders to customers`". **Wrong**. Since the table Customers is joined through left-joined table Orders, it has to be left-joined itself... otherwise the inner join will propagate into the previous level(s) and as a result, you will lose all products that have no orders.

That is, once you join any table using LEFT JOIN, any **subsequent tables** that are joined through this table, need to keep LEFT JOINs. But it does not mean that once you use LEFT JOIN, all joins have to be of that type... only those that are dependent on the first performed LEFT JOIN. It would be perfectly fine to INNER JOIN the table **Products** with another table **Category** for example, if you only want to see Products which have a category set.

*(Answer is based on this answer: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic247971-8-1.aspx -> last entry)*